# Handle cookbook version depends on environment

Tags: chef-infra, devops

I have one doubt. I have created cookbook for application, at the time of build, I am changing the attribute of the cookbook based on the environment. So at the end of build, I have few artifacts generated. one for actual product and other few are cookbook artifacts per environment. 
Now , my doubt is, how the version can be handled here for each cookbook?
In the build process, I can have just one version, but if I apply the same version to all cookbooks then they will override each other when I run the chef-client on selected node.
Can someone please suggest how can I handle this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The version of the cookbook can be managed under `metadata.rb`.

```
name             'helloworld'
maintainer       'YOUR_COMPANY_NAME'
maintainer_email 'YOUR_EMAIL'
license          'All rights reserved'
description      'Installs/Configures helloworld'
long_description IO.read(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'README.md'))
version          '0.1.0'
```

If Chef environment is created based on *Dev* or *Prod* or *Test*, we can have a cookbook version tagged under each environment, so that there wont be any conflict when you run chef-client.

For eg.

**env_dev.rb**

```
name "development"
description "The master development branch"
cookbook_versions({
    "nginx" => "<= 1.2.1",
    "apt" => "= 0.0.2"
})
```

**env_prod.rb**

```
name "production"
description "The master production branch"
cookbook_versions({
    "nginx" => "<= 1.1.0",
    "apt" => "= 0.0.1"
})
```